# Compute $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{J^2_{n}(k)}{k^m} dk$

Tags: calculus, analysis, special-functions

Question as the title showed,in which J means Bessel functions, n and m are positive integers. How to get the analytic result? Any comment is much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.How to simplify  the following formula when $n>2m+1$ and $n$ is odd.
[image]

Comment: All results to integrals of this kind are in terms of [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: @Lucian Will you give the expression as hypergeometric functions?

Comment: [Certainly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XYXcS.png).

Comment: @Lucian May I have the details when Bessels in different order, like $J_n(k) J_{n+1}(k)$?

Comment: Are you asking me to evaluate $~\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac{J_a(k)~J_b(k)}{k^m}~dk~$ in closed form ?

Comment: If so, then the answer can be found [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JHrZA.png).

Comment: @Lucian how to simplify the following when $n>2m+1$ and $n$ is odd.

Comment: I don't think that there are any substantial simplifications to be made.

Comment: @Lucian While when I program to compute this, how to handle the case when n>2m+1 and n is odd?

Comment: Again, I'm not quite sure what's there to “handle”. What precisely is it that seems to be troubling you ?

Comment: @Lucian If n=2m+3, $\Gamma(1/2+m-n/2)=\Gamma(-1)$, how to do with $\Gamma(-1)$?

Comment: In that particular case, we are dealing with an indeterminate expression of the form $\infty-\infty$, but, by taking the limit as $n\to2m+3$, we obtain [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OT6Vq.png).

Comment: @Lucian Excuse me, but I can not link to this result.

Comment: @Lucian Thank you very much. Which software do you use to compute it?  Would you like to show me if n>2m+1 and an odd, namely, n=2m+2s+1 with s positive integer?

Comment: @Lucian Would you mind showing me detailed derivation?

Comment: Uhm, no, I wouldn't mind, but, unfortunately I don't possess one... :-$)$ It was the computer that evaluated the expression, not me... :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian Which math software do you use to compute?

Comment: I use *Mathematica* and *Maple*.

Comment: @Lucian Would you like to show me if n>2m+1 and an odd, namely, n=2m+2s+1 with s positive integer?

Comment: @Lucian I am not very familiar with those two software.

Comment: The same formula holds for all positive values of *n*.

Comment: @Lucian Which formula do you mean? I want a genernal formula that can be used for programming.

Comment: The one you already posted in the body of your own question.

Comment: @Lucian But i can not use that to program as I said $\Gamma(-N)=\infty$

Comment: Unfortunately, as I've already said, answering your question would require applying l'Hopital's rule to the entire expression, which will ultimately lead to handling derivatives of hypergeometric functions, with which I personally am extremely unfamiliar, so I'm afraid I can't be of any further help.