# Proving that $\int_0^\infty\frac{J_{2a}(2x)~J_{2b}(2x)}{x^{2n+1}}~dx~=~\frac12\cdot\frac{(a+b-n-1)!~(2n)!}{(n+a+b)!~(n+a-b)!~(n-a+b)!}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, bessel-functions

> How could we prove that $$\int_0^\infty\frac{J_{2a}(2x)~J_{2b}(2x)}{x^{2n+1}}~dx~=~\frac12\cdot\frac{(a+b-n-1)!~(2n)!}{(n+a+b)!~(n+a-b)!~(n-a+b)!}$$ for $a+b>n>-\dfrac12$ ?

---

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200624), I sought to find $($a justification for$)$ the closed form expressions of

the following two integrals: $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{J_A(x)}{x^N}~dx~$ and $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{J_A(x)~J_B(x)}{x^N}~dx.~$ For the former,

we have $~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{J_{2k+1}(2x)}{x^{2n}}~dx~=~\frac12\cdot\frac{(k-n)!}{(k+n)!}~,~$ for $k>n>\dfrac14~,~$ which I was ultimately

able to “justify” $($sort of$)$ in a highly unorthodox manner, using a certain trigonometric integral 
 expression for the [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), and then carelessly $($and shamelessly$)$ exchanging the order 
 of integration. Unfortunately, even such underhanded tricks have failed me when attempting 
 to approach the latter. Can anybody here help me ? Thank you !

Comment: Cannot we just exploit the fact that $$\mathcal{L}(J_a)(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}\left(s+\sqrt{1+s^2}\right)^a}$$?

Comment: By integration by parts, we just need to find the integral of $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\left(J_a(2x)\cdot J_b(2x)\right)\frac{dx}{x}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: All approaches are welcome, as long as they are correct and complete.

Comment: Try Ramanujan's Master Theorem with the sum for $J_n(x)J_m(x)$.

Comment: @Argon: **IT WORKS !!!** Feel free to post a sketch of your approach, along with a proof for the not so trivial fact that $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}{n+a\choose k+b} ~=~ {2n+a\choose n+b},$$ and I'll accept your answer ! :-$)$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the product cited [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1213437/27624), viz.

\begin{align}
J_{\mu}(x) \, J_{\nu}(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, \Gamma(2n+\mu+\nu+1) \, \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+\mu+\nu}}{n! \, \Gamma(\mu+\nu+n+1) \, \Gamma(\mu+n+1) \, \Gamma(\nu+n+1)} \\
\implies  \frac{J_{\mu}(\sqrt x) \, J_{\nu}(\sqrt x)}{x^{\mu/2+\nu/2}} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, \Gamma(2n+\mu+\nu+1) \, x^n}{2^{2n+\mu+\nu} n! \, \Gamma(\mu+\nu+n+1) \, \Gamma(\mu+n+1) \, \Gamma(\nu+n+1)} \\
\end{align}

we can invoke Ramanujan's Master Theorem, to get

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{J_{\mu}(\sqrt x) \, J_{\nu}(\sqrt x)}{x^{\mu/2+\nu/2}} x^{s-1}\,dx = \Gamma(s) \frac{\Gamma(-2s+\mu+\nu+1)}{2^{-2s+\mu+\nu}\, \Gamma(\mu+\nu-s+1) \, \Gamma(\mu-s+1) \, \Gamma(\nu-s+1)}
\end{align}

If $x=4 u^2 \implies dx = 8u\,du$, the LHS becomes

\begin{align}
2^{2s+1-\mu-\nu}\int_0^\infty J_{\mu}(2u) \, J_{\nu}(2u) u^{2s-\mu-\nu-1}\,du 
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty J_{\mu}(2u) \, J_{\nu}(2u) u^{2s-\mu-\nu-1}\,du = \frac{\Gamma(s) \Gamma(-2s+\mu+\nu+1)}{2\, \Gamma(\mu+\nu-s+1) \, \Gamma(\mu-s+1) \, \Gamma(\nu-s+1)} \\
\int_0^\infty J_{2\mu}(2u) \, J_{2\nu}(2u) u^{2s-2\mu-2\nu-1}\,du = \frac{\Gamma(s) \Gamma(-2s+2\mu+2\nu+1)}{2\, \Gamma(2\mu+2\nu-s+1) \, \Gamma(2\mu-s+1) \, \Gamma(2\nu-s+1)}
\end{align}

Set $s=\mu+\nu-n$.

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{J_{2\mu}(2u) \, J_{2\nu}(2u)}{u^{2n+1}}\,du &= 
\frac{\Gamma(\mu+\nu-n) \Gamma(2n+1)}{2\, \Gamma(\mu+\nu+n+1) \, \Gamma(-\mu+\nu+n+1) \, \Gamma(\mu-\nu+n+1)} \\
&= \frac{(\mu+\nu-n-1)!(2n)!}{2(\mu+\nu+n)!(-\mu+\nu+n)!(\mu-\nu+n)!}
\end{align}

This is your solution.

Answer (score 11):

To save from typing a result a highlight will be listed for now.

1. The integral in question is a reduction of the more general integral
   \begin{align}
   \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{J_{\mu}(at) \, J_{\nu}(bt)}{t^{\lambda}} \, dt = \frac{b^{\nu} \Gamma\left( \frac{\mu + \nu - \lambda +1}{2}\right)}{2^{\lambda} \, a^{\nu - \lambda +1} \, \Gamma\left( \frac{\lambda + \mu - \nu +1}{2} \right) } \, {}_{2}F_{1}\left( \frac{\mu+\nu-\lambda+1}{2}, \frac{\nu-\lambda-\mu+1}{2}; \nu+1; \frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}} \right).
   \end{align}
   When $\mu \rightarrow 2 \mu$, $\nu \rightarrow 2 \nu$, $a=b=2$, $\lambda = 2n+1$ the result is obtained
2. A method to obtain the above listed result is to consider the integral as
   \begin{align}
   \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{J_{\mu}(at) \, J_{\nu}(bt)}{t^{\lambda}} \, dt = \lim_{s \rightarrow 0} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s t} \, t^{-\lambda} \, J_{\mu}(at) \, J_{\nu}(bt) \, dt
   \end{align}
3. See [G. N. Watson's Bessel function Book section 13.4, p.401](https://archive.org/stream/ATreatiseOnTheTheoryOfBesselFunctions/Watson-ATreatiseOnTheTheoryOfBesselFunctions#page/n409/mode/2up)

---

Edit:
The product of two Bessel functions, as required by this problem, is
\begin{align}
J_{\mu}(x) \, J_{\nu}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, \Gamma(2n+\mu+\nu+1) \, \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+\mu+\nu}}{n! \, \Gamma(\mu+\nu+n+1) \, \Gamma(\mu+n+1) \, \Gamma(\nu+n+1)}
\end{align}
When $x = 2t$ it is seen that
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} \, t^{- \lambda} \, J_{\mu}(2t) \, J_{\nu}(2t) \, dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, \Gamma(2n+\mu+\nu+1) \, \Gamma(2n+\mu+\nu-\lambda+1) \, \left(\frac{1}{s}\right)^{2n+\mu+\nu-\lambda+1}}{n! \, \Gamma(\mu+\nu+n+1) \, \Gamma(\mu+n+1) \, \Gamma(\nu+n+1)}
\end{align}
Reducing this series and a possible transformation of the resulting hypergeometric series along with the limiting value for $s$ will yield the desired result.

Answer (score 7):

*Note:* Here is an outline of an alternate proof, which could be helpful.

In section $21$ in *[Bessel Functions and Their Applications](https://books.google.de/books?id=qy1GNv2ovHQC%5C&pg=PA74#v=onepage%5C&q%5C&f=false)* B.G. Korenev introduces the so-called *discontinuous integrals of Weber-Sonin-Schafheitlin* 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{J_\mu(at)J_\nu(bt)}{t^\lambda}\,dt
\end{align*}
He notes, that some special cases of these integrals were calculated by Weber; for all values of the parameters $\lambda,\mu,\nu$ such that this integral converges it has been calculated by Sonin; Schafheitlin in his investigations has noted that at $a=b$ this integral has a *discontinuity*.

Korenev provides in his book a summary of the main points of the proof and refers at the end of the section to volume II of H. Bateman's classic *[Higher Transcendental Function](http://apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol2.pdf)* for more details.

The relevant part in volume II  is section $7.7.4$ *The discontinuous integral of Weber and Schafheitlin*. We find in

> *[H. Bateman] Volume II, Section $7.7.4$:*
>
> We shall now investigate the integral
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_0^{\infty}\frac{J_\mu(at)J_\nu(bt)}{t^\rho}\,dt
> \end{align*}
>   in which are $a,b$ are positive real. It turns out that even when the integral converges for all positive $a$ and $b$, its analytic expression is different, according as $a$ is smaller, equal to, or larger than $b$. The results are
>
> \begin{align*}
> \int_0^\infty&\frac{J_\mu(at)J_\nu(bt)}{t^\rho}\,dt\\
> &=\frac{a^{\mu}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{1}{2}\mu-\frac{1}{2}\rho\right)}
> {2^\rho b^{\mu-\rho+1}\Gamma(\mu+1)
> \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{1}{2}\rho-\frac{1}{2}\mu\right)}\tag{1}\\
> &\quad\cdot {}_{2}F{_1}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{1}{2}\mu-\frac{1}{2}\rho,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\mu-\frac{1}{2}\nu-\frac{1}{2}\rho;\mu+1;\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)\\
> &\\
> &\Re(\nu+\mu-\lambda+1)>0,\quad \Re(\rho)>-1,\quad0<a<b
> \end{align*}
>
> with a corresponding expression for $0<b<a$ [interchange $a$ and $b$] and
>
> \begin{align*}
> \int_0^\infty&\frac{J_\mu(at)J_\nu(at)}{t^\rho}\,dt\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{{\left(\frac{1}{2}a\right)}^{\rho-1}
> \Gamma(\rho)
> \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{1}{2}\mu-\frac{1}{2}\rho\right)
> }{2
> \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{1}{2}\rho-\frac{1}{2}\mu\right)
> \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{1}{2}\rho+\frac{1}{2}\mu\right)
> \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{1}{2}\rho+\frac{1}{2}\mu\right)
> }\\
> &\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\Re(\nu+\mu+1)>\Re(\rho)>0,\quad a>0
> \end{align*}

Note, that substituting in (2)
\begin{align*}
a\rightarrow 2,\quad t\rightarrow x,\quad \mu\rightarrow2a,\quad \nu\rightarrow2b,\quad \rho\rightarrow2n+1
\end{align*}
we obtain 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty&\frac{J_{2a}(2x)J_{2b}(2x)}{x^{2n+1}}\,dx\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{
\Gamma(2n+1)
\Gamma\left(b+a-n\right)
}{
\Gamma\left(b+n-a+1\right)
\Gamma\left(b+n+a+1\right)
\Gamma\left(-b+n+a+1\right)
}
\end{align*}
corresponding to OPs expression.

In order to proof the formulae above Bates continues as following

> ([Bates] adapted:) We use in the integrand of (1) a generalization of Neumann's formula,
>   \begin{align*}
> J_{\mu}(at)J_{\nu}(bt)=\frac{1}{\pi}(2t)^{\mu+\nu}&a^\mu b^\nu
> \int_{-\frac{1}{2}\pi}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}e^{i\theta(\mu-\nu)}\left(\frac{\cos \theta}{\lambda t}\right)^{\mu+\nu}
> J_{\mu+\nu}(\lambda t) \,d\theta\tag{4}\\
> &\\
> \Re(\mu+\nu)>-1,&\quad\lambda=\left(2\cos\theta\left(a^2e^{i\theta}+b^2e^{-i\theta}\right)\right)^\frac{1}{2}
> \end{align*}
>   interchange the order of integration, evaluate the integral with respect to $t$ by
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}J_\mu(at)t^{\rho -1}\,dt&=
> 2^{\rho -1}a^{-\rho}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\mu+\frac{1}{2}\rho\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\mu-\frac{1}{2}\rho\right)}
> \tag{5}\\
> &\\
> -\Re (\mu)&<\Re (\rho)<3/2,\quad a>0
> \end{align*}
>   and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \int_0^{\infty}&\frac{J_{\mu}(at)J_{\nu}(bt)}{t^{\rho}}\,dt=
> \frac{1}{\pi}a^{\mu}b^{\nu}2^{\frac{1}{2}\mu+\frac{1}{2}\nu-\frac{1}{2}\rho-\frac{1}{2}}
> \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\mu+\frac{1}{2}\nu-\frac{1}{2}\rho+\frac{1}{2}\right)}
> {\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\mu+\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{1}{2}\rho+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\\
> &\qquad\cdot\int_{-\frac{1}{2}\pi}^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}e^{i\theta(\mu-\nu)}\left(\cos \theta\right)^{\frac{1}{2}(\mu+\nu+\rho-1)}
> \left(a^2e^{i\theta}+b^2e^{-i\theta}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}(\rho-\mu-\nu-1)}\,d\theta
> \end{align*}
>   But the integrand on the right-hand side is expressible as a hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$, compare volume I, 2.4(11)
>   and we immediately obtain the expressions (1) and (2) according as $b>a$ or $b=a$.

Please note, it is more an outline of a proof since some details are omitted. But it's hopefully useful for further study.

---

*Hint:* When looking for an answer, I also found in chapter $4$, *Bessel Functions and Confluent Hypergeometric Functions* in *[Special Functions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521789885)* by J. Andrews, etal.

> *Exercise 15:* Show that when $a=b$ in Exercise $14$, the result is
>   \begin{align*}
>  \int_0^{\infty}\frac{J_{\alpha-\beta}(at)-J_{\gamma-1}(at)}{t^{\gamma-\alpha-\beta}}\,dt
>  &=\frac{(a/2)^{\gamma-\alpha-\beta-1}\Gamma(\gamma-\alpha-\beta)\Gamma(\alpha)}
>  {2\Gamma(1-\beta)\Gamma(\gamma-\alpha)\Gamma(\gamma-\beta)}
> \end{align*} 
>   provided that $\Re (\alpha)>0$ and $\Re( \gamma-\alpha-\beta) > 0$.
>
> In Exercise $14$ which is a more general variant of the integral above there is a also reference pointing to *[Watson [1944]](https://archive.org/stream/ATreatiseOnTheTheoryOfBesselFunctions/Watson-ATreatiseOnTheTheoryOfBesselFunctions#page/n409/mode/2up)* section 13.4, as we already now from the answer of @Leucippus. In fact the expression in Exercise $15$ is stated as formula (1) on p. $403$ in Watsons book.

So, it could be worthwile to read chapter $4$ about Bessel functions in J. Andrews's book. It consists of roughly $40$ pages, which provides all knowledge necessary to fully grasp Watson's proof.