# Integral involving Bessel functions of the first kind

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, approximation

I am stuck with the following integral. Does it converge?

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(J_1(x)^2+J_1(x)J_1(x)^{''}\right)\text{d}x
$$

According to tables I find that the first term is divergent, so I assume it is overall divergent but it could very well be that the second term tames it.

Edit: It seems that only for the second term to be $a J_1(x)J_1(x)^{''}$ with $a=1$ the integral can be shown to converge, in other cases the divergent part $J_1(x)^2$, for example when $a=1/2$, cannot be substracted by the proposed identities, right?

Comment: $I~=~\dfrac2{3\pi}.$

Comment: sorry, I liked all solutions indeed but I liked the idea with the fourier transform and the plancherel id. more in the end, even if it is more technical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $J_1$ is a solution of the [Bessel differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html):
$$ x^2 f'' + x f' + x^2 f = f \tag{1}$$
by exploiting integration by parts we have that:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(J_1(x)^2+J_1(x)\,J_1''(x)\right)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{J_1(x)}{x}\right)^2\,dx \tag{2} $$
so we just need to recall that the Fourier transform of $\frac{J_1(x)}{x}$ is given by:
$$ \mathcal{F}\left(\frac{J_1(x)}{x}\right)(t) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sqrt{1-t^2}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(-1,1)}(t)\tag{3}$$
to be able to state:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(J_1(x)^2+J_1(x)\,J_1''(x)\right)\,dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\left(1-t^2\right)\,dt = \frac{2}{3\pi}\tag{4}$$
as a consequence of Parseval's theorem.

Comment: As a colorful note, this is my second problem of the day for which the answer is given by $\frac{2}{3\pi}$, the first one being http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243160/expected-area-of-triangle-formed-by-three-random-points-inside-unit-circle/1243173#1243173

Comment: Funny, who would have thought that "The expected area of a triangle formed by three randomly chosen points inside the unit circle" would equal $\int_0^{+\infty} (J_1(x)^2+J_1(x)J_1''(x))\,dx$? :)

Comment: +1 Back!  Your solutions are most often full of creativity and breadth.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio: Do you have a comment on the edit for me? That would be cool. Thanks!

Comment: @Hamurabi: yes, you are right, the last case the integral is converging only when $\alpha=1$. That follows from the fact that $J_1$ decays like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ (it is straighforward to prove by exploiting the Fourier transform), hence $a=1$ is needed in order to grant integrability.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, simpler is better ...

So, let's just start with the identity that Chappers provided, namely

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} (J_1(x)^2+J_1(x)J_1(x)'')\,dx= \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\infty} J_1(x) (J_1(x)+J_3(x)) \, dx $$

Then, let's substitute the recurrence relation

$$J_2(x)=\frac{x}{4} (J_1(x)+J_3(x))$$

to find that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} (J_1(x)^2+J_1(x)J_1(x)'')  \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{J_1(x)J_2(x)}{x}  \, dx $$

Finally, let's exploit the orthogonality relationship

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{J_{\alpha}(x)J_{\beta}(x)}{x}  \, dx =\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}(\alpha-\beta))}{\alpha^2-\beta^2}$$

with $\alpha =2$ and $\beta =1$ to obtain

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{J_{2}(x)J_{1}(x)}{x}  \, dx =\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}(2-1))}{2^2-1^2}=\frac{2}{3\pi}$$

which recovers the expected result!

Comment: (+1) Even simpler than mine. Fourier transform seems to be the key.

Comment: (+1) Ah yes, of course I forgot about that recurrence relation, despite having drilled it into undergraduates a few months ago.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica says it converges to $2/(3\pi)$. You can probably get this from [this identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#E57):
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{J_{\mu}(at)J_{\nu}(at)}{t^{\lambda}}dt=
\frac{(\frac{1}{2}a)^{\lambda-1} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\mu+\frac{1}{2}\nu-\frac{1}{2}\lambda+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma(\lambda)}{ 2\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\lambda+\frac{1}{2}\nu- \frac{1}{2}\mu+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} \lambda+\frac{1}{2}\mu-\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\lambda+\frac{1}{2}\mu+\frac{1}{2}\nu+\frac{1}{2}\right)} $$
with careful limits as $\lambda \to 0$, and the expression
$$ J_1''(x) = \frac{1}{4} (J_3(x)-3 J_1(x)) $$
reduces to the integral to one of the form
$$ \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\infty} J_1(x) (J_1(x)+J_3(x)) \, dx, $$
which you can then do with the linked identity.

Comment: I posted a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213371) asking for a proof of the above identity weeks ago, but found no satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Lucian: maybe it is possible to use the argument in my answer to give an answer to that question, too. It looks reasonable that by switching to Fourier transforms we get a product of values for some Beta functions.

Comment: @Lucian I'm surprised that Watson's book didn't contain a satisfactory answer!

Comment: Thanks!  And a "+1" Back!  I was in the midst of solving this and had arrived at the intermediate identity when you posted.  After pursuing a bit more I arrived at quite a simple way forward.

Comment: @Chappers: That book is well above my pay-grade. :-$)$ I was hoping for an easier approach, one that even the likes of me could understand. :-$)$